# Iteratively adding new lists as values to a dictionary

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have created a dictionary (*dict1*) which is not empty and contains keys with corresponding lists as their values. I want to create a new dictionary (*dict2*) in which new lists modified by some criterion should be stored as values with the corresponding keys from the original dictionary. However, when trying to add the newly created list (*list1*) during every loop iteratively to the dictionary (*dict2*) the stored values are empty lists.

```
dict1 = {"key1" : [-0.04819, 0.07311, -0.09809, 0.14818, 0.19835],
         "key2" : [0.039984, 0.0492105, 0.059342, -0.0703545, -0.082233],
         "key3" : [0.779843, 0.791255, 0.802576, 0.813777, 0.823134]}
dict2 = {}

list1 = []


for key in dict1:
    if (index + 1 < len(dict1[key]) and index - 1 >= 0):
        for index, element in enumerate(dict1[key]):
            if element - dict1[key][index+1] > 0:
                list1.append(element)    

        dict2['{}'.format(key)] = list1

        list.clear()

print(dict2)
```

The output I want:

```
dict2 = {"key1" : [0.07311, 0.14818, 0.19835],
         "key2" : [0.039984, 0.0492105, 0.059342],
         "key3" : [0.779843, 0.791255, 0.802576, 0.813777, 0.823134]}
```

Comment: There are several problems in the code as shown that would prevent it from running at all. `dict2.[` has a stray `.`, and `index - 1` would produce an `IndexError` on the first try.

Comment: Please construct a [mcve] that actually runs. Your code does not run as-is and it does not produce the output you say it does.

Comment: Please define `key1`, `key2` and `key3` as well as `values1`, `values2`, and `values3` because without those your code *still does not run*. Also, please include the desired result for `dic2`.

Comment: @timgeb I've added an example.

Comment: @PhilE thanks, we still need the `dic2` you want.

Comment: @timgeb My bad, I've specified it now.

Comment: @Mark You should post that as an answer, not a comment.

Comment: @PhilE On a side note, don't use the name `list` for a variable. Python already defines this name in the builtin classes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that `list` always refers to the same list, which you empty by calling `clear`. Therefore all values in the dict refer to the same empty list object in memory.

```
>>> # ... running your example ...
>>> [id(v) for v in dict2.values()]
[2111145975936, 2111145975936, 2111145975936]
```

It looks like you want to filter out negative elements from the values in `dict1`. A simple dict-comprehension will do the job.

```
>>> dict2 = {k: [x for x in v if x > 0] for k, v in dict1.items()}
>>> dict2 
{'key1': [0.07311, 0.14818, 0.19835],
 'key2': [0.039984, 0.0492105, 0.059342],
 'key3': [0.779843, 0.791255, 0.802576, 0.813777, 0.823134]}
```

Comment: Thank you! This is what I also suspected. However, the filtering of the negative values was jsut an example. My question is really aimed at how to save a list iterately as a value to a new dictionary.

Comment: @PhilE With a for loop, you just need to be sure to create a new list on each iteration rather than reusing the same list over and over.

Answer (score 1):

[@timgeb gives a great solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71354942/1440565) which simplifies your code to a dictionary comprehension but doesn't show how to fix your existing code. As he says there, you are reusing the same list on each iteration of the for loop. So to fix your code, you just need to create a new list on each iteration instead:

```
for key in dict1:
    my_list = []
    # the rest of the code is the same, expect you don't need to call clear()
```

Comment: Thank you so much, that solved my problem!